# SQL: get count of articles in two categories

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL db I have a table storing the association of articles and categories, columns are category_id and product_id. So the article #5 belonging to categories #3 and #6 has the rows (3,5)(6,5).

Now I need to get the count of articles which are both in category 1 and 6. Getting the count of articles in one category is easy with `SELECT count(category_id) from s_a_c where category_id=1` but how do I expand this Query to check for two cats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with two joins (one join for each category you want to search for):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM articles
INNER JOIN s_a_c c1 ON articles.product_id = c1.product_id
    AND c1.category_id = 1
INNER JOIN s_a_c c2 ON articles.product_id = c2.product_id
    AND c2.category_id = 6
```

And here's another way with a `HAVING` clause. The derived table pulls all products from `s_a_c` with category 1 and 6, having both (`COUNT(1) = 2`). This takes advantage of the fact that `{product_id, category_id}` will be unique:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id
    FROM s_a_c
    WHERE category_id IN (1,6)
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your table by product, then filter the groups for those that match your desired criteria (using the `HAVING` clause, which is evaluated *after* grouping whereas `WHERE` clauses are evaluated *before* grouping):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT   article_id
  FROM     s_a_c
  WHERE    category_id IN (1,6)
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = 2
) t
```

If `(product_id,category_id)` are guaranteed to be unique (e.g. through a uniqueness constraint enforced by a `UNIQUE` key), you can use the more performant `COUNT(*)` in place of `COUNT(DISTINCT category_id)`.

If you need to implement more complex logic on the group filter, you can take advantage of MySQL's lack of genuine boolean types thus:

```sql
SELECT   article_id
FROM     s_a_c
WHERE    category_id IN (1,3,6)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING   SUM(category_id = 1)
     AND SUM(category_id = 6)
     AND NOT SUM(category_id = 3)
```

Note that I continue to include a `WHERE` clause in order that MySQL can use an index to avoid a full table scan if possible.

Answer (score -1):

To get all articles (may have duplicates) in two categories (one and two)

```
SELECT count(category_id) from s_a_c where category_id=1 or category_id=2
```

To get all articles (without duplicates) in two categories (one and two)

```
SELECT count(category_id) FROM s_a_c WHERE category_id=1 or category_id=2 GROUP BY article_id
```

Comment: a Category_id can never have 2 values at the same time

Comment: My apologies, use OR instead

Comment: As @bluefeet commented, the first of these queries will not return any results due to the impossible `WHERE` clause (that is, `category_id` cannot simultaneously equal both 1 and 2); and the second of these queries will return a record for every article that is in *either* category (not both categories), and furthermore each result will merely contain the number of records that associate that article with categories 1 or 2.  It's most definitely not what the OP was after.  -1

Comment: Indeed, you are correct on your second point @eggyal. You'll notice, however, that I had already edited the first query to use the OR keyword. Just thought I'd mention...

Comment: Ah yes.. strangely that hadn't refreshed before!  In any event, that only gives the number of products in *either* category (and at that, only if there are no duplicates), not the number of products in *both* categories (which is what the OP wanted).

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Misread  - this original query does if exists in either or category:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM s_a_c WHERE category_id IN (1,6);`

The correct query for existing in BOTH categories:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM s_a_c WHERE category_id = 1 AND category_id 6;`

TBH, this all really premature w/o seeing the schema for `s_a_c`.

Comment: the same field can never have two different values at the same time